# Javascript not being called onclick

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am new in Javasricpt and i am developing an application using Google Maps API. 
I'm trying to call a javascript function from onclick event but is not being called.
Please if anyone see any errors or something i am missing let me know, I will appreciated. Below is my code.

This is javascript code:

```
 <script>
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var Center=new google.maps.LatLng(18.210885,-67.140884);

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var properties = {
    center:Center,
    zoom:18,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), properties);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }
function makeRoute() {
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(18.210885,-67.140884);
    var end =new google.maps.LatLng(18.2098150,-67.1418260);
    var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
      };

    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    } else { alert("couldn't get directions:"+status); }
    });
}

</script>
```

This is my form:

```
 <form method="post" action="">
          <table border="0px" style="border-radius:5px; border-color: #888888; background-color: #FFFFFF; box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;"><tr>
          <td><b>Get directions:</b></font><br/></td>
          </tr><tr><td align="right">Building:</td><td>
            <select name="building">
              <option value="#" default >Select</option>
              <option value="monzon">Monzon</option>
            </select></td></tr><tr>
          <td align="right">Room:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="room" placeholder="eg. 208B / CH 116" ></td>
          </tr><tr><td></td>
          <td align="right" ><input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="makeRoute()"></td></tr></table>
        </form>
```

Comment: are you getting any javascript errors from the debugger?

Comment: can you add: window.alert("is it working?"); to the first line of the makeRoute function and see if anything happens?

Comment: Shouldn't we be using onsubmit here instead of onclick?  Or even better, creating a handler to grab a click action on that element?

Comment: Hi, I added window.alert("its working"); and the function is being called. But for some reason when i am calling it it doesn't show any results and i am not getting anything in the Javascript debugger.

Comment: Another thing, the function works perfectly when is called form initialize() functon.

Comment: You must cancel the click-event, otherwise the form will be submitted and you don't see any changes, because the page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_directionsForm.asp)

You need to return false here:

```
<td align="right" ><input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="makeRoute(); return false;"></td></tr></table>
```

To prevent the page from reloading and displaying the empty map.